# Rule of thumb for exploratory data

Tags: experiment-design, exploratory-data-analysis

I frequently perform 2k factorial design of experiments and fit the data to a linear regression to control/optimize processes in a manufacturing environment.  I have noticed recently that a large portion of my experiments must be revised fairly early due to faults in my experiment model (e.g. my experiment for dry film thickness was yielding values of 3-8mils and my target value was 1.6mils).  This is worrisome because I occasionally want others to collect the data.

Is there a rule of thumb for when or how much exploratory data is needed for this type of DOE?  Or any advice on the matter?

Comment: You might receive an answer if you give more info: what is DOE in that context? I do not understand what you mean about data not being positioned around the expected outcome...